# Использование переменных js в match

Tags: javascript, match

```
var s='+380974444408';
var phone='+38097';
var phone_digs='08';

s.match(/\+38097[0-9]{5}08/g);
```

Как вставить правильно переменные `phone` и `phone_digs` в match, чтобы было примерно так:

`s.match('/\'+phone+'[0-9]{5}'+phone_digs+'/g')`

Такой способ, к сожалению, не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете новый объект [RegExp](http://javascript.ru/RegExp)

```
var pattern = new RegExp( phone + '[0-9]{5}' + phone_digs, g );
console.log(s.match(pattern));
```